# Break before end of Bluebird.all

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

Is there any way to stop execution of P.all if an error is thrown inside one of the waited promises?

In this example, I expected to see "THE_END" after "A - 1000", and not after "B - 100000"

```
const P = require("bluebird");


const p1 = P.resolve().then(() => {
  for(let i = 0 ; i <= 1000 ; i++) {
    console.log("A - ", i);
  }
  return Promise.reject(new Error('error'))
});

const p2 = P.resolve()
  .then(() => {
    for(let i = 0 ; i <= 100000 ; i++) {
      console.log("B - ", i);
    }
  });

return P.all([p1, p2])
  .catch(() => console.error("THE_END"));
```

Comment: No. That return happens long before any errors  can occur.

Comment: Short answer is no. You already initialized the resolve in p2

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `P.all`, use [`P.some`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.some.html) and pass the number of Promises:

> If too many promises are rejected so that the promise can never become fulfilled, it will be immediately rejected with an `AggregateError` of the rejection reasons in the order they were thrown in.

i.e.

```
return P.all([p1, p2], 2).catch(() => console.error('error'));
```

however please note that your hypothetical example won't work as desired anyway because your "busy loop" of repeated calls to `console.log` will tie up the browser's event loop.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you could for example add a function to check if a binary variable is set to 0 before executing P.all. Then when it's called once for example, you could set it to 1.